# When does a control in Silverlight get released\destroyed?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is there any documentation around the life cycle of a control in Silverlight?

Specifically I'm interested when a control is released (memory garbage collected) when used as part of an item template in a listbox, so when new items are bound to the listbox when do the old controls (no longer bound) get released?

I'm not interested in the workings of the GC and the ideas behind a manageed environment.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule of thumb applies to control objects as well. They are collected when no one references them and GC starts collecting.

Just to make it clear, unloading of a control is different than garbage collecting.